# sound monitoring using python

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to write a script using Python that will check if another program on my computer makes a sound.  Can't seem to find a clear solution for this.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this may not be possible at all, depending on (a) your operating system, (b) your sound system, and (c) your hardware. It's a very platform-specific question. If you specify your platform someone might have a solution for you, however.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 using the on board sound.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't think what you want exists, but you may have some luck looking through this list: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic